# Golang to match dash(hyphen) character

Tags: regex, go, regex-negation

Golang to match dash(hyphen) character

```
regexp.MustCompile(`[^[:alnum:]\s]`)
```

This matches `-`(dash) character

But I want a regex that excludes the dash character.

I tried the following but it greps the `+` characters:

```
regexp.MustCompile(`[^[0-9A-Za-z\-]\s]`)
regexp.MustCompile(`[^[0-9A-Za-z-]\s]`)
```

How do I match characters that are not `alphanumeric` and not `-`(dash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I match characters that are not alphanumeric ,not -(dash) and not a space?

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s-]
```

Remove the extra character classes from your regex. The above regex would be fine.

Comment: How do I include the `\s` then? Thanks!

Comment: This regexp is not valid in Golang. I am running v1.20.